# Adding blink animation in iOS without using NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I want to add a blink animation in my app. For that purpose, I have used the code below.

```
if (buttonFlashing) return;
        buttonFlashing = YES;
        self.img_one.alpha = 1.0f;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.12
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut |
         UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat |
         UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse |
         UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^{
                             self.img_one.alpha = 0.0f;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             // Do nothing
                         }];
        mode_count=1;
```

It works fine to hide & show the image view but I want to show another image when image is hidden then again show the previous image using above code. Above code just hides & shows the image view by using it's alpha. How can I do it?

Comment: use two imageview when first imageview alpha=1.0f that time set second imageview alpha=0.0f and when first imageview alpha=0.0f that time set second imageview alpha=1.0f

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.imageView
                  duration:1.2f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse |UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                animations:^{
                    self.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"phone-icon.png"];
                } completion:NULL];
```